# What's the point of the Devise Registrations controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I presume there's some value-add from using the Devise Registrations controller but I haven't yet managed to figure it out.

Other than signing the user in after they're created, why would you use the Devise Registrations controller rather than simply having

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new

  end

  def create
     @user = User.create params[:user]
     sign_in :user, @user
     redirect_to... # whatever's next
  end
end
```

What does the core Devise Registrations controller do that the Users controller doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for yourself

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

If you think it's not worth it, then don't use it.

Comment: Fair point - I did take a look and there are a couple of extras in there.